# Get route not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, get

I have registered get route like below:

```
Route::get('/user/verify?email={email}&token={token}', 'UserController@verifyEmail');
```

But when I try to access this route with the following:

```
website.com/user/verify?email=example@gmail.com&token=38757e18aad8808832ace900f418b03763789755
```

It says `404` not found. What is wrong here?

Comment: your route would be `Route::get('/user/verify', 'UserController@verifyEmail');` now call `website.com/user/verify?email=example@gmail.com&token=38757e18aad8808832ace900f418b03763789755`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your route would be :

```
Route::get('/user/verify', 'UserController@verifyEmail');
```

Now can access :

```
website.com/user/verify?email=example@gmail.com&token=38757e18aad8808832ace900f418b0376378975
```

In your controller you can get the parameter value like that :

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
   $email = $request->email ?? null;
   $token = $request->token ?? null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `php artisan route:list` in your console and check how exatctly every route looks like.

Query params like that: `?email={email}&token={token}` in this url: `'/user/verify?email={email}&token={token}'` are ignored by laravel router.